# "How much do" or "How much does"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-agreement

I am very confused by this article title in New Yorker:

[How Much Do Pacquiao-Mayweather Tickets Cost?](http://www.newyorker.com/news/sporting-scene/how-much-do-pacquiao-mayweather-tickets-cost)

Shouldn't it be "How much does"? Why *do*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> How much do Pacquiao-Mayweather tickets cost? (Better off without capitalization when you're asking a question from your friend)

The misunderstanding, I believe, is caused by these two guys: Pacquaio and Mayweather.

If you run into this kind of problem, I suggest

### 1. Finding out what the verb is pertaining to:

Isn't the sentence like this?

> How much does/do ____ cost?

We need to fill that blank with either *something* or *somethings*. To find out which, do the next step.

### 2. Omitting the elements of the noun phrase:

What are the words in this phrase? *Pacquiao-Mayweather* and *tickets*. We eliminate both. The one that makes sense, has the [head](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHead_%2528linguistics%2529&ei=5h9FVbXBGYHkUIvUgsgG&usg=AFQjCNGlGAfgI1MlHu__XN6kUKUBTMt9qg&sig2=72bcnBT-jll2R76FfYIMIg) of the phrase.

> How much do * *Pacquiao-Mayweather* cost?
>
> How much do *tickets* cost?

You see, the price is about the tickets. So, *tickets* is the head of the noun phrase.<sup>1</sup>

### 3. Applying the subject-verb agreement:

Verbs, generally, follow (or agree with) the nouns they're pertaining to. In this step, after we have identified the head of the noun phrase, we have to write a verb that *agrees* with it.

*Tickets* is a plural noun. So, the verb needs to be plural.

> How much do/<strike>does</strike> *tickets* cost?

Done like a charm! <sup>2</sup> :)

---

<sub>1: If you want a more comprehensive way of determining the head of noun phrases, visit [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/phrases/ex2.htm).

2: If things are still vague, you can leave me a comment.</sub>

Comment: 2. Notice that "Pacquiau-Maywether" is acting as a _modifier_ for "tickets"; thus the names are NOT nouns and could NOT be the subject for "cost". We don't have to try them out to see if they "make sense" as the "head".

Comment: @Brian The name(s) certainly is a noun (word class / part of speech) that modifies tickets. What else would it be? What is *office* in *office building?*

Comment: *Modifier* is a function, *noun* is a class.  Being a modifier does not mean something isn't a noun.

Comment: Okay, let's just say the names _are not **acting** as nouns_, and therefore _could not be the subject for "cost"_.  happy now?